# How to make collapse row in row in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to expand and collapse my `section` in angular js, but not able to get proper result.

First I make simple demo of `collapse/expand` in angular js. which is working fine
https://plnkr.co/edit/Rxc3As7qI65rajp6Wv47?p=preview
above example works fine `see first-row collapse/expand` .

I used the same concept in another example where I want `table` having `different sections` example `GENERAL_INFORMATION` and `User INFORMATION`. I want to `collapse/expand` these sections.

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/0ME41KD2jkbbYZzJYf6C?p=preview

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in name">
    <uib-accordion>
      <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.open">
          <uib-accordion-heading>

            <td ng-if="value.type == 'LABEL'" colspan="2" style="background: #777; color: white;">
                {{key}}
            </td>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
      </div>
   </uib-accordion>

    <td ng-if="value.type == 'FIELD'">{{key}}
        <span ng-if="value.required">
            <sup class="required">*</sup>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td ng-if="value.type == 'FIELD'"
    >
        {{value.value}}
    </td>      
</tr>
```

any update?

Comment: You might want to fix the invalid HTML caused by adding unsupported tags inside a TABLE tag. The TABLE tag is pretty finicky and requires a strict use of TABLE > TR > TD structure without any DIVs in between.

Comment: can you share your plunker

Comment: I did not create one. I just noticed that a DIV tag is inside a TR tag, which means it is removed when rendered in the browser as that is unsupported.

Comment: ok..!! do you have . any idea to implement collapse and expand list

Comment: Because of this limitation with the `uib-accordion`, a custom solution might be needed as shown elsewhere: http://johnculviner.com/expandable-collapsable-detail-in-a-table-with-angular-js/

Comment: it is not neecessary to use table ..!! we can use `ul` `li` but list should be collapsible and expendable

Answer (score 0):

Using basic AngularJS techniques, the effect can be achieved by using a combination of `ng-if` with a `show` variable which can be toggled.

If there are more than one heading and content combinations, you can achieve that with an array of `show`.

This snippet shows the basic technique. However, you might want to encapsulate the behavior in a directive such as the `uib-accordion` does.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.show = [];
    $scope.show[0] = false;
    $scope.show[1] = false;

    $scope.toggle = function(index) {
      $scope.show[index] = !$scope.show[index];
    };
  }]);
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.heading {
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 150px;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
}


/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */

.fade.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}


/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */

.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="myController">
    <tr class="heading">
      <td ng-click="toggle(0)">
        Heading
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="show[0]" class="fade">
      <td class="content">
        Content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="heading">
      <td ng-click="toggle(1)">
        Heading
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="show[1]" class="fade">
      <td class="content">
        Content
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```